Comparar dos arreglos de objetos y obtener la diferencia de los dos arreglos con base al objeto que tenga el mismo valor de id en C#
podrían ayudarme a obtener la diferencia de dos arreglos de objetos, eliminando en uno de estos el objeto que tenga el mismo ID en ambos arreglos. Ejemplo
tengo la clase persona{
 
   Id;

   Nombre:

}

y tengo dos arreglos de esta clase
Primer arreglo persona
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Nombre": "Juan"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Nombre": "Mario"
  }
]

Segundo arreglo persona
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Nombre": "Pancho"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Nombre": "Carmen"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Nombre": "Herson"
  }
]

entonces quisiera obtener un nuevo arreglo solamente con los objetos que no están en el otro, en este ejemplo quisiera obtener del primer arreglo solamente este objeto
[
 {
    "Id": "2",
    "Nombre": "Mario"
  }
]

porque el otro existe en el segundo arreglo con el mismo Id = "1"
Existirá alguna manera. Gracias.
Edit:
Esto surge debido a que en principio tengo un datagridview entonces
hice algo asi
MiClase[] obj = new MiClase[dgv.RowCount];
              for(int x =0;x<dgv.RowCount;x++)
                {
                    obj.Id= 
                      dgv.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    obj.Nombre=
                      dgv.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                   
                }

Luego tengo el arreglo nuevo de objetos y lo que hago es esto
  ArrayList objTercero = new ArrayList ();

        for(int x = 0; x < obj.Length; x++)
            {
                  //objSegundo ya contiene los nuevos objetos
                if (obj[x].Id!=objSegundo[x].Id)
                {
                    objTercero.Add(objSegundo[x]);
                }
            }

y hago un envío de un JSON que con un arreglo de objetos, y el problema es que el ID lo genero aleatoriamente, por lo que en el WebService falla el registro porque se generan algún id que ya está registrado y es llave primaria. Pero me gustaría que ignoren este edit y si conocen de una solución con el primer ejemplo simple está bien, creo que me servirá para adaptarlo e igualmente para quien busque algo similar lo podrá adaptar, mi intención es obtener una solución general y no solo para mi caso. Gracias.
SEGUNDO EDIT: SOLUCIÓN CON BASE A LA RESPUESTA DE @Yussef
Persona objPersona;//Para crear las nuevas personas en el for
List<Persona > resul = new List<Persona>();

public async Task CrearPersona(int cantidad, Persona[] objPersonasArreglo)
{
            Persona [] objPersonas= new Persona [cantidad];


//Ciclo para ir creando los objetos y a su vez guardalos dentro de un Arreglo del mismo tipo
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
            {
               //Random con semilla
                Random parteID= new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond + i);

                //Método GenerarID que genera el ID
                string ID = GenerarID(parteID);

                objPersona= new Persona();

                objPersona.ID= ID ;
                objPersona.Nombre= "El nombre";
                objPersona.OtraPropiedad = "otroValor";
                objPersona.OtraPropiedad = "otroValor";
                objPersona.OtraPropiedad = "otroValor";
                objPersonas[i] = objPersona;
                //barra_prograso.Increment((int)incremento);
            }

//Aquí aplico la solución de @Yussef
resul = objPersonas.Where(a => !objPersonasArreglo.Any(b => a.ID == b.ID)).ToList<Persona>();

}

y el resul lo envío como JSON y que también gracias a @Yussef en una duda que tuve sobre APIS y PHP me dio la respuesta para registrar en un solo request POST todos los objetos!
//Esto  es PHP, lo dejo por aquí para que conozcan igual esta forma tan elegante hacer multiples registros en una sola petición POST
function RegistrarPersona($conexion)
{
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $valor = [];
    foreach ($datos as $row) {
        $valor[] = "('$row->ID','$row->Nombre','$row->OtraPropiedad ','$row->OtraPropiedad ','$row->OtraPropiedad ')";
    }
//Aquí aplico la solución de @Yussef que me dio en una publicación
    $sql = "INSERT INTO personas(ID,Nombre,columna,columna) VALUES" . join(",", $valor);
    $conexion->query($sql);
}

Muchas gracias por las respuesta también a @Juan Alzate también intenté usando Contains(), pero pasa algo raro, usando != me guardaba los objetos y usando == no me los guardaba jajaja, y también probé otras formas. Gracias de nuevo.

Y probaste algo?? se me ocurren varias formas de hacerlo...

No entiendo. No se repite ningún elemento

@gbianchi si, puse alguna de las últimas formas que hice, aunque eso no es todo, ya que estoy pasando información entre capas, pero solo necesito alguna solución, intenté por parte del servidor, pero no conozco mucho por ese lado y no pude probando con las varias funciones que tiene PHP para comparar arrays, por eso espero encontrar una solución en C#, que creo si lograrlo, pero ando en otras cosas y si alguien ya ha hecho algo similar o le es fácil la solución yo con gusto recibo la ayuda. Gracias.

@Yussef Jeje pues que te digo, desde que me registre hace 3 días o 4 días y con eso de que termino y nada mas no finalizo este proyecto, jejejeje lo siento, si había puesto eso, de hecho cuando apagué el ordenador para comer y descansar, mientras comía recordé ese detalle y dije ostias que menso jejeje, solo que de nuevo estoy al ruedo a casi de ya terminar esto (otra vez lo digo). Me uní aquí solo por esto, especialmente por las APIS que bueno, es difícil explicar pero tengo el internet muy limitado y no puedo investigar mucho menos ver vídeo, solo espero conseguirdineroal menosparasobrevivr.

Digamos que tienes algo como esto:

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Persona[] array_A = {
            new() { Id="1",Nombre="Juan"} ,
            new() { Id="2",Nombre="Mario"} ,
        };

        Persona[] array_B = {
            new() { Id="1",Nombre="Pancho"} ,
            new() { Id="3",Nombre="Carmen"} ,
            new() { Id="4",Nombre="Herson"} ,
        };

    }
}
public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

Para encontrar los elementos de array_A que no se encuentran en array_B (solo por su Id) haces:
var result = array_A.Where(a => !array_B.Any(b => a.Id == b.Id));

Donde array_B.Any(b => a.Id == b.Id) devuelve true si exsite alguna Id en array_B que exista en array_A. A esto lo negamos con !, por tú quieres lo inverso "que NO exista". Y luego aplicamos el filtro con Where

@Yuseef Que pro, gracias, me das la solución y me ahorras líneas de código! de casualidad no eres el creador de C# jejeje. Gracias.

@José ajjajajajaja gracias por tus palabras. Me alegro haber podido ayudarte

hola, estoy intentado eliminar de un mismo arreglo el objeto con el mismo ID, estuve intentando con Distinc() pero no me funciona, estaba viendo la documentación y existe la forma implementando la   IEquatable interfaz genérica en la clase según esto https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-8.0   y siendo sincero no lo he probado porque ando viendo como solucionar otro problema con la carga lenta de un datagridview, pero me gustaría saber si existe una forma corta similar como la solución que diste en esta publicación. Gracias de antemano

@José var sin_repetidos = array_B.DistinctBy(a=>a.Id); algo así??

Si, pero duda, tu puedes usar DistincBy? yo lo he intentado pero no me aparece y tengo las referencias de System.Data.Entity y también Linq, revisando algo aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060937/linq-distinctby-with-multiple-fields-does-not-contains-a-definitions-for-distinc  dicen que no forma parte de las funciones y se debe hacer eso, esto es cierto? o me falta en verdad alguna referencia? con Data.Entity precisamente para solucionar la carga lenta de registros en un datagridview existe según la función ToListAsync misma que tampoco puedo hacer uso. Gracias por responder.

@José Si puedo, sin instalar nada adicional, yo uso .net 8.0, tú que versión estas utilizando? Lo de la carga lenta ya es un tema a parte, te recomiendo usar Stopwatch en varias partes de tú código para determinar donde se produce el problema. Adicionalmente puedes realizar una pregunta referente a eso

Estoy con .Net Framework, no puede ser, intentaré actualizar, no lo entiendo la verdad, se supone que DistincBy está disponible igualmente en este. Si, de hecho ya hice una publicación, hasta ahora solo el mismo moderador de siempre que pide detalles, crítica y casi que se burla muy arrogante, como ellos hay un montón, muy pocos como tú Yussef, aquel solo pide pero solo eso porque ya no responde jejeje. En fin que me sirva de lección tal vez para la otra tal vez haga directamente en .Net solo, o sino intentaré implementar esa clase para usar DistincBy, ya casi me voy a dormir. Gracias!

@José .Net 8.0 es infinitamente superior a la 4.X. Si es que aun estas a tiempo te recomiendo que te cambies a la última versión. Pero para responderte, podrías hacer algo como var sin_repetidos = array_B.GroupBy(a=>a.Id).Select(a=>a.First());

Podrías intentar usando el método Contains(), este devuelve true si el valor que indica está dentro del array.
Acá te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como utilizarlo:
string[] array1 = { "1", "2", "4" };
string[] array2 = { "1", "2", "3" };

List<string> array3 = new List<string>();

foreach (string x in array1)
{
    if (!array2.Contains(x))
    {
        array3.Add(x);
    };
};
Console.WriteLine(array3);

El valor con el que termina el array3 es el 4 ya que ese es el único valor que no se encuentra en el array2.
Adaptándolo a su ejercicio sería algo como esto:
 Persona[] array1 = {
     new() { Id="1", Nombre="Juan" },
     new() { Id="2", Nombre="Mario" },
 };

 Persona[] array2 = {
     new() { Id="1", Nombre="Pancho" },
     new() { Id="3", Nombre="Carmen" },
     new() { Id="4", Nombre="Herson" },
 };

 List<Persona> array3 = new List<Persona>();

 for (int x = 0; x < array1.Length; x++)
 {
     if (!array2[x].Id.Contains(array1[x].Id))
     {
         array3.Add(array1[x]);
     };
 }

 Console.WriteLine(array3);

Obteniendo como resultado en el array3:
{ Id="2", Nombre="Mario" }

Esto está mal -> if (!array2[x].Id.Contains(array1[x].Id)), debería ser if (array2[x].Id != array1[x].Id)

@Yussef - Esta es otra forma de hacerlo -> if (array2[x].Id != array1[x].Id), pero no significa que la forma que yo propuse esté mal, solo hay diferentes formas de hacerlo.

@JuanAlzate Muchas gracias! tendré presente tu respuesta. Gracias en verdad.

No @JuanAlzate no es otra forma, eso está mal. Prueba cambiando el Id de "Carmen" a 200 y vas a ver lo que ocurre. Tu estas comprobamos si el string contiene otro string, tal como la palabra "Casandra" contiene a la palabra "Casa" o la palabra "200" contiene a la palabra "2"
